# Fixing an AMD R9-280X

Tags: graphics-card

I have a GIGABYTE R9-280X and for a while now, it shows in every game I play (Battlefield 4, Rust, Minecraft, League of Legends etc..) a defective render, usually arround the sky area.

A video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19d4SuzUOlk

*This is not a game specific issue, because it happens in multiple games.

I have updated to the latest drivers, and downgraded to old ones, which did not help.

My best guess is that I have defective graphics memory, thus it tries to read and it reads garbage.

This happens for over 6 months now, and the card is out of warrenty. Is there anything I can do before throwing it away?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're willing to risk breaking the card entirely (beyond any reasonable hope of repair), you can *try* certain things that may or may not help. Your success or failure with these remedies depends on certain things:

- Whether or not the remedy you're attempting is able to fix the specific problem you're having
- The degree to which you execute the procedure for the remedy correctly and accurately and without doing anything that might accidentally cause more damage
- Whether you've successfully guessed or deduced the actual problem and have done enough research to identify the solution most likely to fix it without causing more damage

Now, just to challenge your idea that you think you know what you're doing, and to play devil's advocate, I claim that you have *not* yet gathered enough information to exhaustively know that it's the graphics memory (GDDR5) chips that are bad.

The justification for my claim is simple:

1. There appears to be some kind of pattern that governs which areas of the scene are most likely to be rendered incorrectly.
2. This corruption could just as easily be due to damaged components of the GPU core itself, or some of the traces on the board, because the skybox rendering might be invoking specific types of GPU commands that trigger the behavior.
3. It is unlikely that, in a random access memory, every game you play stores the texture data of the skybox in the same region of memory. I suppose this is possible if they all use the same engine, but not likely outside of that.

AMD GPUs are designed in a "GIGO" (Garbage In, Garbage Out) fashion. This means there is very little data integrity/sanity checking on the GPU itself, except that certain low-level constraint violations cause a GPU hard-lockup (which would manifest itself probably as a BSOD or at least a TDR on your computer).

At a very high level, there are three "phases" a draw call on a GPU:

Phase 1: **Input** - transferring *commands* and accompanying *data* to the GPU. Potential sources of corruption or hardware damage include bad PCIe lanes, insufficient/bad power supplied to the GPU, bad data delivered from the operating system into the GPU (software/driver bug), etc.

Phase 2: **Processing** - where the GPU takes *commands* it's received, *data* it's received from the CPU, and processes them, storing intermediate results in the VRAM. From this point, additional GPU commands could cause the GPU to continue to manipulate the data more and more in VRAM, or even *read* data back from VRAM into the CPU. Sufficiently complex game engines and/or driver stacks probably do a little of both of these.

In the processing phase, you might have a board trace connecting areas of the board that has been impaired in such a way that the GPU stops working correctly, but doesn't detect the problem so it never locks up or crashes. Or there may be degradation of the actual transistors in the GPU due to stress or heat.

Phase 3: **Output** - where the GPU takes "finished" graphics data, composites it all together (kind of like assembling the pieces to a puzzle, or overlaying sheets of different colored film on top of one another), then writes it out to the framebuffer (which gets read from by the display controller that then pushes it over the HDMI/VGA/DVI/DP port). Alternatively, it might get read back to the CPU at this stage, then written back to the framebuffer using software. Depends on the driver/engine architecture specifically in use.

It's not terribly likely that your problem is in the output phase if your desktop works normally when not playing a game, since anything related to the framebuffer or the display controller would probably manifest regardless of what kind of rendering you're doing.

If I had to guess, I'd say that the VRAM is not a very likely suspect, but rather, some specific fixed-function area of the GPU that is responsible for handling skyboxes or occlusion culling or something, is damaged, or a trace going to it is damaged.

That said, there are a few solutions you can try, ranging from safe to dangerous to very likely to break your card:

1. **Safest** - Go into AMD Catalyst Control Center. Under AMD Overdrive, underclock your GPU. Underclock it at first by a little, then by *a lot*. This is perfectly safe and guaranteed not to damage your GPU, since it voluntarily runs at an "underclocked" speed when idle, anyway. Sometimes problems only manifest when the GPU is under heavy load. If yours is a problem like that, this will fix it by reducing load on the GPU at any given time (and also reducing heat). You'll get lower FPS, though.
2. **Safest** - Try another operating system, like GNU/Linux (e.g. Ubuntu), to see if the problems manifest there. If not, the GNU/Linux driver implementation may be hitting areas/functionalities of the GPU not affected by the damage, or maybe it's always been a software problem all along and there isn't any hardware defect at all.
3. **Safe** - Try to clean your GPU and PCI Express slot physically. Don't use any corrosive chemicals. Gently wipe off the pins on the card that interface with the PCI Express slot, too.
4. **Slight Risk** - Try updating your GPU's firmware code. There are websites hosting various versions of the VGA BIOS for both AMD and Nvidia graphics cards. Make sure to match up the exact model. Then compare the versions. If you don't have the latest version installed, *get* the latest version. You can flash it safely using a stock AMD flasher utility in most cases. If you download the wrong ROM, you could possibly brick your card, but this is very unlikely on the R9 280X, because you can always flip the dual ROM switch on the board (a tiny switch that lets you have two separate versions of the ROM/BIOS/firmware installed at once) to go back to the factory firmware. Just make sure not to break the second copy of the factory firmware too, or you're really dead in the water.

In general though, your risk incurred by flashing the firmware is *low-ish*, especially on a dual-BIOS card. Even if your power goes out while you're flashing it, you just flip the switch to revert to factory, and move on. I personally have flashed an HD7970/R9 280X about 10 times. It's really quite casual, compared to what else I have to suggest.

---

Beyond this point in my answer, I just want to emphasize how dangerous this is, and I disclaim any responsibility for any damage you incur to your hardware for trying this. It is very likely that doing this improperly will result in you completely bricking your card.

5. **Super Dangerous** - Try [baking](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/bake-a-gpu.171887/) your GPU. Just google "bake GPU" and you will get hundreds of user stories, some happy but most sad, stating one of four outcomes: either it fixed the problem permanently, fixed the problem temporarily, didn't fix the problem but didn't damage the GPU further, or broke the GPU. **A VERY SIGNIFICANT PORTION** of the people who try this report that it breaks the GPU. This may be due to improper treatment on their part, but the fact remains that this is super risky. You could also burn your hands on the hot material if you aren't careful, or even start a fire if you are reckless.

The general concept here is that you want to have a hot baking oven (**NOT a microwave - very important!**) and quickly get your GPU up to just a high enough temperature to make the solder a little melty. This "reflows" the solder and can possibly repair certain *types* of damage. It *is not* a cure-all, and it *can* (and often does) break the card completely. It's very timing and temperature-sensitive and is not for the faint of heart.

6. **Super Hard and Dangerous** - It's physically possible to replace or upgrade the VRAM on your graphics card. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnnU5-83QUM) is a Youtube video demonstrating the procedure. However, the following constraints present themselves immediately:

   - You need the right tools and the right physical control of your hands to do this without breaking anything.
   - You need to know the *exact* part number of a compatible GDDR chip(s) that will work with your GPU. Understanding how to find the right part is outside the scope of this question/answer.
   - You need to be able to put everything back together after you're finished, again without damaging anything.

And of course, this solution has no relevance if your GDDR is not damaged/defective in the first place. The unfortunate part is that it's not very easy to determine *whether* the problem lies with the GDDR or elsewhere. You might be able to write some software that's the equivalent of memtest86 but for the GPU, but I've never heard of such a thing.

And of course, the last one:

7. **Super dangerous** - *Know an AMD employee who's a graphics card hardware engineer*. :) They probably fix stuff like this all the time while doing development/testing/verification. It's super dangerous because even if you are friends with the person, asking them to do this for you will likely result in them yelling at you or smacking you. :)

Comment: What an answer!

Answer (score 0):

The only advice that can be given is to get it replaced where you purchased it from but if you have been suffering for 6 months i think you may be too late.

Try it in another computer, if it doesn't work then you need a new one.

Comment: As noted, the card is out of warranty.